# Classic ASP Conditional If statement Corrupting style sheet

Tags: css, if-statement, asp-classic

Can anyone tell me why the conditional if statement regarding the font size is not working. This code is from an asp/css style sheet that is used by other webpages. When I take out the IF statement the stylesheet returns to being working with the If statement for the back ground colour.

I think it looks correct and ive double checked it countless time for the syntax but it definately isnt working. It runs in conjunction with a simple form page. The Response.Cookies("sizeFont") is stored on another page and I know this is working because I printed the value to the screen for testing.

Code from my asp/css style sheet:

```
TH, TD { border: 3px solid black; padding: 1}

<%
bgc= Request.Cookies("choicebgc")
If(bgc = "brown") then
    Response.Write("body{background-color:#D99756}")
ElseIf(bgc = "green") then
    Response.Write("body{background-color:#8EB16A}")
End If
%>
<%
font= Response.Cookies("sizeFont")
If(font= "12") then
    Response.Write("p{font-size:12pt}")
ElseIf(font= "16") then
    Response.Write("p{font-size:16pt}")
End If
%>
```

Comment: I've never seen ASP embedded in a stylesheet before, it this even possible?

Comment: Appears that this exact question is already, recently, posted on another site: http://forums.iis.net/p/1196780/2046984.aspx/1?Classic+ASP+Conditional+If+statement+Corrupting+style+sheet

Comment: @AndersUP yeah, hah, nothing wrong with that though.

Comment: So I guess the question is if this is the OP of that post, or someone trying to find an answer for that post.  Either way, I don't think we want to encourage such blatand cross-posting.

Comment: I've made some changes to the question to try to make it more readable and improve the spelling/grammar.  Feel free to revert if you don't like my changes.

Comment: @jbabey I'd say there is - partly due to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site - and in this question also due to the fact that the OP hasn't even bothered taking out the header information from the other site.

Comment: @AndersUP agreed, as the accepted answer on that question states, the cross-post should be announced upfront on both sites with links back and forth so answerers do not waste their time.

Comment: Hi there, I posted the same question here because I have gotten no reply's on the other site, I was not aware of this cross posting rule. If i get an answer here i will gladly update the other site. Regards, Trevor

Comment: @TrevorWalsh Actually, I stand corrected - I brought up the question on Meta (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174997/213634) and, as you can see, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response.Cookies? Dint you mean Request.cookies?

Comment: YES YES, your a gentle man and a scholar. Thank you very much Schar. I just had a look at the other site that I put the same question up and I still have no responses. That is why I put the same question up here. I knew I would get an answer quicker. But in the future I will declare it before hand and apologies for not doing so. And i will let the other site know that this has been answered.